# Neo4j and CVE-2021-44228

Tags: neo4j

Is Neo4j impacted by CVE-2021-44228? Which versions of Neo4j are concerned?

Is it possible to mitigate the vulnerability by setting the log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups parameter as described in this [post](https://www.randori.com/blog/cve-2021-44228/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of Neo4j > 4.2 are affected. The described workaround does work.

Until versions with a fix are available, please add the following lines to your neo4j.conf file:

```
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true 
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true
```

You need to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Edit 14.12.2021:

New versions of Neo4j with fixed dependencies are available

- 4.2.14
- 4.3.8
- 4.4.1