# Is neo4j 3.5 impacted by CVE-2021-44228?

Tags: security, neo4j, log4j

I found that only neo4j > 4.2 is impacted by this vulnerability ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70308545/neo4j-and-cve-2021-44228) and [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12796) )

But in neo4j 3.5.21 pom I see a dependency to log4j ([here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5.21/pom.xml)):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

So is this version really safe for use in production environment right now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that `log4j` version `1.2.17` is used in `neo4j 3.5.21` and this version is not vulnerable to https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228 as the vulnerability was introduced with version 2.10.0.

In any way `log4j` version `1.2.17` is vulnerable to https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571 which has a score of 9.8 out of 10. It is a different attack vector maybe harder to exploit, but same as critical and should not be used in production.

You should update your neo4j version in any way.

Comment: In my opinion all software changes should be considered against the value and cost of implementation. If the use case of Log4j in the software is not impacted by any vulnerabilities, then upgrading an older package is likely not worth the cost.

Comment: In general I agree that you have to weight cost and reward of an update. But speaking about a large product like neo4j or e.g. spring, that comes with many dependencies, you should always try to stay up to date in time as these come with a lot of dependencies, which can all bring in vulnerabilities. Updating multiple times shortly after the releases is simpler than doing big bang migrations later on. You will run into more errors and find less sources to fix your problems.

Answer (score 1):

**The sky is not falling.** To be clear Log4j 1.2.17 does *NOT* suffer from the ZDV. Are you running the rarely used network socket appender or JDBC appender servers? Is Neo4j? (I don't think so.) If you are not, then there is no reason to urgently toss software in the trash that relies on [Log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).*****

One thing for sure is that Log4j2 is a breaking API change, which means you cannot just stuff a new JAR in and hope it works. (Package names and config specs changed.) If code is written well using a logging abstraction layer, like [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html), then it's a snap. However, if code relies on programmatic config settings, there will be pain. Upgrading to Log4j2 can be a non-trivial task.

***** Note that Log4j 1.x has been out of its support window for a few years now. Also, Log4j2 was a complete rewrite of the API that is less resource intensive, less locking and quite faster (thanks to the [LMAX Disruptor](https://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html)). There are reasons to upgrade but not as an emergency.

Comment: Using the socket **appender** is fine too, what is vulnerable is running the socket server (the receiving part of the socket appender).

Comment: Thanks @PiotrP.Karwasz for making that distinction. Yes, it is the receiving end that poses the potential problem. (It's _potential_ because in the case of CVE-2021-4104 [related to the JMSAppender server] the steps to duplicate actually require system access to modify the config file to make it vulnerable.